# How to access the single child from equalTo(unique) query, without forEach

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to access the resulting object (key:value) from a query. Here is my query:

```
root_ref.child('List_Groups').orderByValue().equalTo(group_name).once('value')
.then(function(snapshot){...
```

The data I'm querying is in this form:

```
List_Groups
  uniqueKey: value,
  uniquekey: value,
  ...
```

The purpose of the query is to find the unique key associated with the `equalTo` parameter (`group_name`). I intended to use `orderByValue().equalTo()` to grab the single result since `group_name`is unique. However, the snapshot it returns is of the form:

```
List_Groups
    uniqueKey: group_name
```

So `snapshot.key` returns `List_Groups` and `snapshot.val()` returns `[object Object]`. The key in `[object Object]` is what I need to access.

I have used `forEach` to obtain the key, but `forEach` seems unnecessary to use for this task. Is there another way?

`snapshot.child().key` would be ideal, however this will obviously not work since `child()` requires a child path as a parameter. Also, since I am looking for the key, I do not know the key and thus cannot just `snapshot.val()[key]`.

edit:
This is the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()))`:

`{"-KNgrFphjMX0vlMG2l7G":"newgroup"}`

Comment: @theblindprophet Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't `child(path)` require the path to be a key? In my case `group_name` is the value and I don't yet know it's key. So the path would be `List_Groups/key`.

Comment: Print out `snapshot.val()` like `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));` and post that in the question.

Comment: @theblindprophet Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var theKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];
```

`Object.keys()` returns an array of all the keys in the object and in your case there will only ever be one key, so `[0]` will get the first (and only).

CodePen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/GqGQaJ

Comment: Well that is perfect. Thank you, I would have never thought of that.